# How to change the ordering of nav bar items when I have two nav bars and a single toggle using bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want two navigation bars with a single toggle. The first one is for the logo, email icon and a search box. The one below it is for other links.
When using the toggle in smaller screens, I want the items in the top navbar to appear below the second navbar. I want to it this way:
Home
About
Departments
Admissions
Download
Email
Search

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-light"  style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" id="navtop">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="logo.png"></a> 
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbars">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbars" id="collapse_target1">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item ">
               <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
            <form class="form-inline">
               <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="search" placeholder="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-light btn-sm " type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </form>
        </div>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl sticky-top" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" id="navbottom" >
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbars" id="collapse_target2" >
       <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto" >
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Departments</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Admissions</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Downloads</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: In smaller screens you want to swap the navbars right?

Comment: yes, that is right. I want the order to be changed. The links in the bottom navbar must appear above the links in the first navbar when the user clicks the toggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the order of items between small and larger screens, with the main menu items in a second row, it might be easiest to do it with one navbar and use flex order.

I removed the second navbar and added a container div under the `navbar-collapse` div. The new div is styled (using Bootstrap classes) with `display: flex` and initially set to `flex-direction: column` (so that the menu items go down in a single column) and at the medium breakpoint, the display switches to `flex-direction: row` and `flex-wrap: wrap` so that the main menu will wrap to a second line.

The order starts with the menu items, followed by email and then search. That’s the order the navbar content will be displayed on a mobile device and how it will be read by a screen reader. I used `order-md-1 -2 -3` to change the order for wider screens.

The logo image is position used absolute so its size doesn’t impact the centering of the main menu. The original question did not include any information regarding the logo image, so I used a small placeholder.com image.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light" id="navtop">
    <a class="navbar-brand p-0 position-absolute align-self-start" href="#"><img src="
        https://via.placeholder.com/120x60.png?text=Logo" alt="Logo" style="height: 1.875rem; width: auto;"></a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_target1" aria-controls="collapse_target1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbars" id="collapse_target1">
        <div class="flex-container w-100 d-flex flex-column flex-md-row flex-md-wrap">
            <ul id="lower-nav" class="navbar-nav mr-auto order-md-3 justify-content-md-center w-100">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Departments</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Admissions</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Downloads</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mr-md-0 ml-md-auto order-md-1">
                <li class="nav-item px-3 pl-md-0">
                    <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline mr-auto mr-md-0 order-md-2">
                <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="search" placeholder="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-light btn-sm " type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="content text-center vh-100 bg-info">
    Center
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solutions works perfectly. I also learnt a lot.